My code has loaded the API but it does not continue to run
class StatisticViolationController extends BaseController {
  final _commonRepository = Get.find<CommonRepository>();
  final _statisticViolationResponsitory = Get.put(StatisticResponsitory());
  final PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  late ManagementAreaQuery areaQuery;
  late ManagementCameraQuery cameraQuery;
  late VinQuery vinQuery = VinQuery(page: 0, size: 10, keyword: '', status: 1, sort: ['createdDate','DESC']);
  var firstMenu = <AppMenuInsideItemVM>[].obs;
  var orgId = 0.obs;
  var areaCode = [].obs;
  var vinCode = [].obs;
  var camCode = [].obs;
  List<ManagementArea> areaId = [];


  @override
  void onReady() async {
    super.onReady();
    await getUser();
    areaQuery = ManagementAreaQuery(orgId: orgId.value);
    await getListArea();
    cameraQuery = ManagementCameraQuery(areaId, orgId.value, 1);
    await getListCamera();
    await getListVin();
    getStatisticViolation();
  }

...

Future<void> getStatisticViolation() async {
    StatisticViolationRequest request = StatisticViolationRequest(
        ...
    );
    ....
    );

    try {
      final result = await _statisticViolationResponsitory.getStatisitcViolation(request, query);

      firstMenu.value = [
        AppMenuInsideItemVM(
          content: 'notification_sent',
          contentText: result.data!.total!.notificationSent.toString()
        ),
        ...
}catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

The problem is that the code only runs up to the command
final result = await _statisticViolationResponsitory.getStatisitcViolation(request, query);

I checked by print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); but it not run:

HELP ME
Can you explain to me why?
